# Cannot change values for two css elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have this piece  of code

```
$(function(){
var padding1 = [1,15];
var fontSize = [18,23];


  var changeNavState = function(newStateIndex) {
    $("nav ul li a").data('state', newStateIndex).stop().animate({
        padding : padding1 [newStateIndex] + 'px'
    }, 300); 
    $("nav ul li a").data('state', newStateIndex).stop().animate({
        fontSize : fontSize [newStateIndex] + 'px'
    }, 300); 

  };

  var boolToStateIndex = function(bool) {
    return bool * 1;    
  };

  var maybeChangeNavState = function(condState) {
    var navState = $("nav ul li a").data('state');
    if (navState === condState) {
      changeNavState(boolToStateIndex(!navState));
    }

  };

  $('nav ul li a').data('state', 1);

  $(window).scroll(
      function(){
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('#home').offset().top - $('nav').height()) {
          maybeChangeNavState(1);
        } else {
          maybeChangeNavState(0); 
        }
     }
  );
}
```

);

So when the user scrolls greater than hight of 'home' then the navbar padding should be 1 and font size 18 and when its minor padding should be 15 and fontSize 23. The problem is that it works only for fontSize BUT if i erase fontSize code the padding works.. Does anyone knows what is going on ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the reason or not... but I would change your animation code to:

```
$("nav ul li a").data('state', newStateIndex).stop().animate({
    padding : padding1 [newStateIndex] + 'px',
    fontSize : fontSize [newStateIndex] + 'px'
}, 300);
```

Combining the two together. Perhaps the two are conflicting?

Comment: Thanks bro! That was the problem.. Silly me for not seing that. Cheers. I will tick when i can ;d

Comment: Also, if this was me, I would opt for a css solution: `nav ul li a { transition: all 0.3s; }`